# Windows 2008 dead server to windows 2012 Active directory move

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Our windows 2008 AD server has failed, but i am able to read the hard drive via a usb cradle.
We have got a new server now running windows 2012.
Is there anyway I can move the active directory?

Any help, gratefully received.
Thanks
James

Comment: Where's your other domain controller?

Answer (score 4):

Q: Is there anyway I can move the active directory?

A: No there isn't.

Comment: Move? No. But possible reclaim? Maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have backups?  (It sounds like the answer is no, but...)  If so, restore the 2008 server (to a VM if necessary), add the 2012 machine as a second DC in the old domain, then demote and remove the 2008 server. Then raise the functional level of the domain on the 2012 DC.  For more details on this process, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753104.aspx).  [This article](http://www.techworld.com/tutorial/operating-systems/how-add-windows-server-2012-domain-controller-existing-windows-2008-domain-3410261/) might also help.

I would also recommend a second domain controller, to help prevent outages in the future.